# After switching from Windows 10 back to Linux Ubuntu 14.04, Nvidia won't work for dual monitor

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Since I am using dual-boot laptop connected to a monitor, I sometimes switch between Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu 14.04. The problem is my nvidia driver seems to halt every time I switch from Windows back to Linux.

FYI, I have installed the latest Nvidia drivers following the method provided [on this page](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html). First, I installed Nvidia binary driver 370 for proper display on both monitors. As the next time I switched back from Windows back to Linux, nvidia driver was again halted, forcing me to install nvidia-375 to reclaim proper display resolution on both screens. The 3rd time, the same happened and I had no choice but to re-install the former nvidia370 from the system settings "Software and Update". 
I guess this should relate to certain conflicts between kernels, but I have no knowledge on this domain. Thus, my questions are:

- People were suggesting re-install the nvidia drivers from run files
  with *dkms*, but since I installed mine with binaries, I have no idea
  how to re-install it on this way.
- How to install the nvidia drivers and be done forever?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using binaries install only from the official default repositories or, if a even newer version is required, add the *semi-official* Graphics Drivers PPA.

**Preliminary step:**   Remove any traces of the previously installed Nvidia drivers with `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` .

Add the additional repository and install `nvidia-375`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-375
```

Or search for Additional Drivers, select and apply the desired version.

Reboot.

This drivers are updated when required and are rebuilt for any new kernel. This is the way to *install the nvidia drivers and be done forever* (almost).

Comment: I tried your method as well as 10 other ways and still with no avail. The day before yesterday I switched back to Xorg Xserver, it did work fine with two monitors. Yesterday there was an update that upgraded my kernel from 4.2.0 to 4.4.0 and broke even the Xorg Xserver. I unintentionally removed all necessary dependencies and eventually decided to reinstall the OS to reover the kernel. But I no longer have my second monitor detected by the system. I tried 4 times to install Nvidia drivers but the system only return black screen on the laptop's screen and no signal on the external one.

Comment: Oh, and thank you for your quick response. I was just trying all day long to get two monitors to work properly. I tried installing Nvidia driver on my other laptop, and it equally failed. There should be a standard and safer way to do so. But, thank you anyway !!

Comment: The cards require different driver version but everything else is as standard as you can get. *I tried installing Nvidia driver on my other laptop, and it equally failed*... This suggests you're doing something wrong or you're the unluckiest person in the world. When it somehow fails there's a **preliminary step** that must be done before trying again, another version.